# How do I redo parts of a git imerge result?

Tags: git

[The internet](http://softwareswirl.blogspot.com/2013/05/git-imerge-practical-introduction.html) tells me about `git-imerge`:

> Lets you **test every intermediate state**. If there is a problem, you can use "git bisect" to find the exact pairwise merge that was faulty. You can redo that merge and continue the incremental merge from there (retaining earlier pairwise merges).

But how can I do that?

To start the operation of eg. merging branch `newFeature` to `master`, I would use

```
git checkout master
git-imerge start --name=mergeMyNewFeatureToMaster --first-parent --goal=merge newFeature
```

And then resolve all the conflicts that imerge finds by itself. After finishing, I see that somewhere a bug has been inserted. I search for it using

```
git bisect start
git bisect good ...
git bisect bad ...
...
```

But when I have found the merge commit that introduced the problem – how can I *redo that merge and continue the incremental merge from there*?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way. You might contact imerge's author directly as this seems like something the script should offer.

Comment: I was hoping that it would be so easy that the blog post's author didn't even bother to mention how his/her statement should be achieved...

Comment: @torek, I've added an issue containing my question: https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge/issues/188

Comment: Is it appropriate to ask Stack Overflow about the workings of a third-party tool?

Comment: @matt – I would be surprised if not. Isn't even git itself a third-party tool?

Comment: Hmm, that's a puzzler for sure. But everything is third-party by that reckoning.

Comment: @matt: it's tricky. Michael Haggerty did comment on the new issue and noted that automation for this is indeed missing.